# PHP not posting form enteries to the same page

Tags: php

Here's a form I have. I want to post the form entries to the same page and then do something else with it. However, echoing the values doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the HTML part:

```
<div class="well">
        <form name="myform" class="form-horizontal" id="form" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" action="my.php" method="post">
                <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="text" class="control-label">Field1</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="left">
                                <input id="Field1" name="Field1" type="text"/> 
                             </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
                 <br>
             <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="passwd" class="control-label">Field2</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="left1">
                                <input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="password" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
            <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="passwd" class="control-label">Field3</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="left1">
                                <input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="password"/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="select" class="control-label">Field4</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="left1">
                            <select class="form-control" name="Field4">
                                 <option value="OP1">OP1</option>
                                 <option value="OP2">OP2</option>
                                 <option value="OP3">OP3</option>
                                 <option value="OP4">OP4</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="text" class="control-label">Field5</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="left">
                            <input type="Field5" id="Field5" name="type"/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br>
                <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="text" class="control-label">Field6</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="left">
                            <input type="text" id="Field6" name="Field6"/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="left1">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
                     </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PHP part:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
  echo $_POST['name'];
 } else {?>
<?php;}?>
```

Comment: submit button don't have the name "submit"

Comment: that was so simple. Thank you.

Comment: If you post to the same page, you might as well get rid of the `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>` 

to  
`<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>`

Answer (score 1):

There is no field with the name `$_POST['name']`, though you have fields with numbered names, e.g. `$_POST['Fields3']`.

To debug the form request print out the whole `$_POST` array first:

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

**The `type` of an input is not the same as it's `name`!**

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

with:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Your submit button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
```

does not have a `value`, nor does it have a `name`. Post works with these attributes:

```
$_POST['<name>'] = <value>
```

change your input to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
```

Btw, nice to see people still coding in XHTML. If you are using HTML 5, you should not end your non-closing tags with a slash `... />`.